# Configuration of calling Python script using PHP

Tags: php, python

I am trying setup a project which will have a call between PHP and Python which will execute a script. I am using Mac OS and MAMP server. I read some blogs and documentation and there is `mod_wsgi` and `mod_python` but i'm not getting the any solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if I understood the problem correctly, you are going to execute a python script from a PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

The following code executes python version command on the shell and returns the results of the version. You could do similarly like this to execute your python script.

```
$python = "/usr/bin/python";
$output = array();
$cmd = $python . " -V 2>&1 ";
exec($cmd, $output);
$python_version = $output[0];
```